# Making a method analyzing a given value

Tags: java

I want to make a method that analyze a given value

```
void method(int value)
```

- if this value equals for example 7, I want output to be like this :
  7 = 12 * 0 + 7
- if value = 13 output :  13 = 12 * 1 + 1
- if value = 24 output :  24 = 12 * 2 + 0
- if value = 39 output :  39 = 12 * 3 + 3
- if value = 289 output : 289 = 12 * 24 + 1

and so on
12 is constant

How can I make this ?

Comment: if you can write pseudocode you are also able to write it in java. give yourself a try. We wont make the work for you.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you are looking for

```
12 * x + y
```

This means:

```
x = value / 12;
y = value % 12;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void method(int value) {
  int x = value / 12;
  int y = value % 12;
  System.out.print(value + " = 12 * " + x + " + " + y);
}
```

The method that you are looking for could be something like the snippet that I have written above.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete code:

```
public class SingleItemView {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SingleItemView.getNumber(14); // Pass the value for which you need the expression
    }

    public static void getNumber(int n) {
        int temp1 = 0;
        int temp2 = 0;
        if (n > 12) {
            temp1 = n / 12;
            temp2 = n % 12;
            System.out.println(n + " = 12 * " + temp1 + " + " + temp2);
        } else {
            System.out.println(n + " = 12 * 0 + " + n);
        }
    }
}
```

In your main method you are passing value to the method for which you need to expression.